# How can I find the maximum/minimum and maximal/minimal elements of a poset?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

My teacher has given us really unclear definitions for all these terms, and now I have this assignment due where I have to find the maximum, minimum, and maximal/minimal elements of this poset:
$$A=\{2, 3, 4,...,17\}$$ and define $\le$ on $A$ by $a\le b$ if $ a|b.$
 How?? Help!
(Sorry I don't know how to make the funny less than or equal to sign)

Comment: What's a "poset"?

Comment: @5xum Partially ordered Set.

Comment: I would try and write the set in a lattice to get the best idea about how the ordering is arranged...

Comment: As for the funny $\leq$, do you mean $\preceq$ (`\preceq`)? Googling "detexify" brings you to [this site](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) which is a wonderful tool for that one symbol you don't remember or know how to do.

Comment: Your set doesn't contain $1$. Can any prime in $A$ have a (strict) predecessor? If $n\in A$ and $17<2n$ then no multiple of $n$ can be in $A$, so can $n$ have a (strict) successor? And yes, definitely draw a picture!

Answer (score 2):

Learn by playing with it.

Take a piece of paper and start drawing! Put a $1$ at the bottom and just start drawing arrows. You put an arrow whenever one number evenly divides into another, for example$$1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 16$$ should be in your drawing.

If you manage to draw all the possible arrows you have completely drawn out your poset. Some element will be minimal, in that it will be the smallest possible and there will be a path to every other element.

A maximal element is one that does not point to anything else. So you look at your drawing and just find those.